# “Save and add another” option in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, handlebars.js, bootstrap-modal

This is my first time asking a question here so if you need more information just let me know.

I’m using JavaScript with the handlebars framework.

I have a bootstrap modal which has a form in it. I have 3 buttons on this form (‘cancel’, ‘save’, and ‘save and add another’)

I need the ‘save and add another’ button to submit the form (Which adds the item to the DB), refresh the page behind it so that the list on the page shows the newly added item, and finally keep the modal open so that another item can be added.

Comment: Hi Luke. Welcome to stack overflow. Here is a guide to producing a minimal, reproducible example so that others can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. This snippet is called on the form submit and as the callback of the DB function. I didn't need to refresh the view, just the list that I was changing.

```
                modalPopup.on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
                    if (addAnother) {
                        modalPopup.modal("show");
                        addAnother = false;
                    }
                })
                itemTable.bootstrapTable('refresh');
                modalPopup.modal("hide");
```